# do I need to install both grunt and grunt-cli

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have installed grunt-cli like this `npm install -g grunt-cli`. Then I copied gruntfile.js to my local project folder. I tried to run `grunt` command but got an error that locally installed grunt can't be found. I then installed `grunt` like this `npm install grunt --save-dev` and it worked. So my question is whether I need to install both `grunt-cli` and `grunt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You need a grunt on your package.json and grunt-cli on your computer (global).